# How can I dependably web-scrape a largely unattached line effectively?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Sorry if that was a vague title. I'm trying to scrape the number of XKCD web-comics on a consistent basis. I saw that http://xkcd.com/ always has their newest comic on the front page along with a line further down the site saying:

```
Permanent link to this comic: http://xkcd.com/1520/
```

Where 1520 is the number of the newest comic on display. I want to scrape this number, however, I can't find any good way to do so. Currently all my attempts look really hackish like:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen('http://xkcd.com/').read())
test = soup.find_all('div')[7].get_text().split()[20][-5:-1]
```

I mean.. That *technically* works, but if anything on the website gets moved in the slightest it could break horribly. I know there has to be better way to just search for `http:xkcd.com/####/` within the a section of the front page and just return `####` but I can't seem to find it. The `Permanent link to this comic: http://xkcd.com/1520/` line just seems to be kind of floating around without any kinds of tags, class, or ID. Can anyone offer any assistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I insist on using HTML parsers. Here, since we are looking for a specific text in HTML (not checking any tags), it is pretty much okay to apply a regular expression search on:

```
Permanent link to this comic: http://xkcd.com/(\d+)/
```

saving digits in a group.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> import requests
>>> 
>>> 
>>> data = requests.get("http://xkcd.com/").content
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'Permanent link to this comic: http://xkcd.com/(\d+)/')
>>> print pattern.search(data).group(1)
1520
```